# How to manipulate data object and save into Spring JPA in effective way?

Tags: java, spring-boot

1. How can i save the manipulated object and other object after the "Transaction.builder" at below code in effective way ?
2. Is there any other way for me to set all the object in the builder rather than only the object that i want to ?

(FYI: I have entity class with hundred of object)

```
 ProcessingError error = new ProcessingError("Tag Serial Num and Vehicle Plate Num are empty",
                        ResponseStatus.TAG_SERIAL_NUM_VEHICLE_PLATE_NUM_NOT_EXISTS,
                        TransactionRule.VALIDATE_TAG_SERIAL_NUM_VEHICLE_PLATE_NUM);

log.info("Transaction before builder :{}",transaction.getTcTransactionId());

   transaction = Transaction.builder()
        .responseStatus(error.getResponseStatus())
        .failedErrorRule(error.getTransactionRule())
        .build();

 log.info("Transaction after builder :{}",transaction.getTcTransactionId());
```

Ref full code at top:

log shown in the code before using builder:

```
Transaction before builder :"test01"
```

After
Log shown in the code after using builder

```
Transaction after builder :null
```

Comment: You are reassigning `transaction` variable with a new value that doesn't have `tcTransactionId` initialized. You should either transfer missing fields to a new instance, or populate missing fields within old instance

Comment: @Nikolay Shevchenko TQVM, my silly mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the builder and  just straight set the variable such as in below code:

```
transaction.setResponseStatus(error.getResponseStatus());
transaction.setFailedErrorRule(error.getTransactionRule());
```